# Improve performance of MongoDB $geoIntersects query

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, geospatial

I'm trying to improve a MongoDB query that queries documents by a point. The documents have a simple polygon geometry with between 10 and 100 points and between 50m and 5000m across. An example document:

```
{
    "_id" : UUID("9175a387-4b0c-48ab-a74a-a8b200cc5285"),
    "seconds" : NumberLong(123),
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [ [ 
            [ 28.08093, -26.00869 ], 
            [ 28.09113, -26.01888 ], 
            [ 28.09486, -26.03282 ],  
            [ 28.08093, -26.00869 ] ]
        ]
    }
}
```

The query uses `$geoIntersects` filtering by a point and orders the results by `seconds`. There is a geospatial index on geometry and seconds, and I have tested that it does get used during this query:

```
IXSCAN { geometry: "2dsphere", seconds: 1 }
```

As we are using the MongoDB C# driver this is not the exact query but rather what I retrieved by profiling, but an example of the query is as follows:

```
db.getCollection('fooCollection')
.find({
    "geometry" : {
        "$geoIntersects" : {
            "$geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 28.04, -26.19 ]
            } } } })
.sort({ "seconds" : 1 })
.projection({ "geometry" : 0 })
```

Since we only need geometry for querying, we also project just the id and the seconds field to reduce data I/O. The geometry is an approximation and does not have to be a perfect match.

This query is used during an extremely performance critical task and it is a bottleneck, taking about 170ms to complete. This is nowhere near as quick as our other Mongo queries which typically complete in 20-30ms end to end.

I don't know enough about the internals of the `$geoIntersects` query or geospatial indexes to know if there is any way I can improve the performance of this query. Some (rather time consuming) ideas that I'm not sure are worth pursuing:

- Simplify all the geometry to use fewer points.
- Use a simpler reference geometry than 2dsphere. A flat approximation would be close enough for our purposes.
- Nuclear option: Cache all of the geometry in memory and perform the collision detection ourselves. This is contingent on writing such an algorithm and index lookup as efficient as MongoDB's.

Is there anything I'm missing with this operation? **What is the best way to improve the performance of a MongoDB `$geoIntersects` query?**

EDIT: Added the following explain() output as requested:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "fooCollection",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "geometry" : {
                "$geoIntersects" : {
                    "$geometry" : {
                        "type" : "Point",
                        "coordinates" : [ 
                            28.04, 
                            -26.19
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "geometry" : {
                    "$geoIntersects" : {
                        "$geometry" : {
                            "type" : "Point",
                            "coordinates" : [ 
                                28.04, 
                                -26.19
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "geometry" : "2dsphere",
                    "seconds" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "Geometry_Seconds",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "geometry" : [ 
                        "geometry"
                    ],
                    "seconds" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "geometry" : [ 
                        "[2202260217784172544, 2202260217784172544]", 
                        "[2203386117691015168, 2203386117691015168]", 
                        "[2203667592667725824, 2203667592667725824]", 
                        "[2233785415175766016, 2233785415175766016]"
                    ],
                    "seconds" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 29,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 5,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 58,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 46,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "geometry" : {
                    "$geoIntersects" : {
                        "$geometry" : {
                            "type" : "Point",
                            "coordinates" : [ 
                                28.04, 
                                -26.19
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 29,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 58,
            "advanced" : 29,
            "needTime" : 28,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 46,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 46,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 58,
                "advanced" : 46,
                "needTime" : 11,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "geometry" : "2dsphere",
                    "seconds" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "Geometry_Seconds",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "geometry" : [ 
                        "geometry"
                    ],
                    "seconds" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "geometry" : [ 
                        "[2202260217784172544, 2202260217784172544]", 
                        "[2203386117691015168, 2203386117691015168]", 
                        "[2203667592667725824, 2203667592667725824]", 
                        "[2233785415175766016, 2233785415175766016]"
                    ],
                    "seconds" : [ 
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 58,
                "seeks" : 12,
                "dupsTested" : 46,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "LAPTOP-F7A8SNP5",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.3",
        "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: Should that not be `"geometry.seconds": 1`? There is no path of just `seconds` in your document. With MongoDB being schemaless it's not an "error" to define an index for a property that does not exist any any document since it does not know what the documents *may* contain. But it's certainly not being used from the index if you are applying any additional filtering or ordering within the query. I know you won't be able to provide an example to reproduce the performance in the space here, but an example of what a typical query is looking for would at least give some insight.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn - seconds is not under geometry, I made a mistake copying the document which I have corrected. I have also added the example query you requested. I am actually using the Mongo C# driver so this is not the exact query but rather what I retrieved from profiling the database. Does this help?

Comment: You are looking for an intersection of a "Point" only. is that always the case? Have you tried ( even manually ) to do a "near" query, or specifically a `$geoNear` aggregation stage first in order to only consider polygons within a certain distance? Just wondering if the processing would be more efficient on that operation. Note I say aggregation `$geoNear` purely to "filter" and then of course follow with a `$geoIntersects` in order to actually obtain intersections. Though again, not really sure what you need here. But that is what I would try first.

Comment: You could also probably post the explain output based on the query you found in the profiler logs. And if you find a reliable way of logging the serialized queries from the C# driver itself, then please let me know.

Comment: Yes, always a point only. A pre-filter $geoNear sounds like a really great idea. Would have thought that Mongo would do something like that internally anyway, but perhaps we have extra information (for example, the upper bound on the size of the polygon and a centroid point) that Mongo doesn't know about, which would make a manual pre filter more efficient. I'll try that out, thanks a lot. Not sure what explain output you are referring to as extra information to post?

Comment: `db.getCollection('fooCollection').explain("executionStats").find(<your_query>)`. Tells you useful things about the index usage and number of documents matched, number of docurments in collection,  documents considered etc. That would give some indication on what is happening. As for the `$geoNear`, I'm not certain their is any performance improvement in the query execution "itself" in comparison, but it was essentially the `"maxDistance"` constraint that might be able to be used for consideration. i.e In order to know I'm not about to hit a wall, I don't need to search all walls on earth.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn, I have added the explain() output as you requested, but this is for a test data set on my local database so it's not exactly what is happening in prodution.

Comment: Hi @08Dc91wk, what is the performance of the query when you skip the `.sort({ "seconds" : 1 })` part? If you project just the `seconds` (and maybe the `_id` too?) then you could try sorting by seconds in your C# code?